# Vue асинхронные компоненты

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Начал пробовать Vue и сразу же споткнулся на асинхронности компонентов.

main.js

```
import test_comp from "./components/test_comp";

const AsyncComp = () => ({
    component: {test_comp},
    delay: 2000,
});

$(() => {
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!'
        },
        components: {AsyncComp}
    });
});
```

test_comp.js

```
export default {
    name: 'test_comp',
    data: () => {
        return {
            message: 'hi!'
        }
    },
    template: `<span>{{message}}</span>`,
}
```

Вываливается ошибка

```
main.js:535 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <test_comp> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

На каком моменте у меня случился затуп?

**UPD**:

Во вьюшке сделал

```
<async-comp>
    <test-comp></test-comp>
</async-comp>
```

Ошибки уже нет, но теперь не отображается темплейт компонента, а вместо него `<!---->`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: test_comp и test-comp это одно и то же?

Comment: по идее - да. разницы не заметил между подчеркиванием и тире

Comment: ну вы проверьте как оно точно, потому что HTML5 custom elements, например, обязательно с дефисом по середине.

Comment: Еще бы пример решения, а то тоже голову сломал

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил. В component должен быть Promise.

Comment: Еще бы ответ с примером реализации, а то не тянет на "ответ"